# Live Wallpaper isVisible/onVisibilityChanged not working with Android 9+ App drawer

Tags: android, focus, visibility, live-wallpaper

I have observed No visibility change reported by the ***isVisible()*** and/or ***onVisibilityChanged()*** when a Live Wallpaper is covered by AppsDrawer on an Android 9 phone. I am guessing it's because the Apps Drawer is shown translucent, as you can make out a hint of LWP shown underneath.

Reason I need to be able to determine when AppsDrawer obscures my LWP is, just as the doc says
***It is very important that a wallpaper only use CPU while it is visible**..*
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine

Is there some alternative ways to work out visibility or focus change? not sure LWP really gets a focus

Comment: Let me reframe this: Can we extend the Wallpaper engine to be able to register when the LWP is shown at less than full visibility?

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended: if the live wallpaper is at all visible to the user (even under layers of the launcher), it will be considered visible.

There's no callback for a live wallpaper to know if the app drawer is mostly obscuring the live wallpaper (and different launchers may obscure it much less or much more).

Comment: With different launchers, the old-school variety, the visibility will switch to Invisible when AppsDrawer is shown. The new way of doing doing it translucently has little practical value to end user, yet it precludes me to doing some UX things I want to add when visibility changes.

Comment: As a developer of a live wallpaper app myself, I feel you. There's no way around it, unfortunately.